# how to fix the error of could not early remove libandroid-support:arm (2) in termux

Tags: command-line

I tried to install mariadb via termux in my Android phone, it actually downloaded it but was unable to install. It gave me an error message which goes thus:

```
E: This installation run will require temporarily removing the essential package libandroid-support:arm due to a Conflicts/Pre-Depends loop. This is often bad, but if you really want to do it, activate the APT::Force-LoopBreak option.
E: Internal Error, Could not early remove libandroid-support:arm (2)
```

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: not really a programming code question. This maybe more appropriate on https://android.stackexchange.com but read their help regarding on-topic questions. AND Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: You will not be able to fix this because the developers broke the project: https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/4129

Answer (score 5):

Try this (to forcibly remove everything):

```
rm -rf $PREFIX
```

then restart termux.

Note that you will have to install all packages again. Maybe store the output of `apt list` beforehand.

Comment: Something feels off when an answer says "destroy everything", without specifying a limiting context. There is some "fighting rogue AI" vibe in it...